# Can I pipeline mails using CakeEmail?

Tags: php, email, cakephp

I need to send personalized emails during an invoicing loop. Means each client will receive an email like "Dear Mr. Joe Smith,...". Generating these mail is fine and without errors.

Once I send them each call of the `Send()` method seems to send the individual mail. This means the script connects to the SMTP server, drops the mail and then disconnects. This is very time consuming as I send several hundreds of emails. It leads to an overflow in the PHP execution time. This especially a problem when using large attachments.

I wonder if there is change to send all email to some kind of a buffer or pipeline first. After the loop has ended then the connection is established once, only. Much better would be some kind of a background job doing that.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could set a flag (or a message) in a table, and send emails via a cron job.

Comment: Use [a job queue based solution](https://github.com/nodesagency/cakephp-email-queue). I.e. _don't_ attempt to send mails synchronously.

Comment: @AD7six This looks pretty much like what I was searching for. Thanks. However I understood the console call to CAKE still launches a PHP process. So the timeout will appear again. 

Maybe I just need to time a bunch of 50 mail each 5 minutes and call a regular cron job. Still ugly....but a step forward.

Many thanks to all of you who answered.

Comment: There is no timelimit by default on a cli php process. that plugin is effectively a daemon process - it'll run until there are no mails to send. I'd recommend taking a serious look at the upvoted answer.

Comment: Ahh. Didn't know that. Then this seems to be the best solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Mail` transport in CakePHP and setup your postfix in your webserver to act as a relay for the SMTP server you use. This method is several orders of magnitude faster than anything else you can do in php.

Answer (score 0):

No, [the default SMTP adapter](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/source-class-SmtpTransport.html) can't do that.

You can extend the SMTP adapter and override it or change it as you need to implement that functionality.

```
PersistentStmpTransport extends SmtpTransport {
    /* ... */
}
```

By a quick look, this should be doable within 30-60 minutes at the most. By the way, I think your argument is valid and I'm surprised that this is not already in the transport implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Only to understand the concepts.

CakeEmail just send email

Then, you may need to use a Queue.

There is a plugin for that, checkout http://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-queue

You may need CRON to scheudle.